# How to prevent multiple instances of app/activity when it is started from Intent.createChooser()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a simple app with a single TextView which displays plain text from an ACTION_SEND intent. My issue is that every time that some text is shared to this app a new instance is created. I can see multiple instances of the app on checking the recent apps. I'm testing it on API 23.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("MainActivity.java", "onCreate");

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp_textview)).setText("Share text/links from other apps");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        intent.getFlags();
        Log.d("onResume - intent: ",intent.toString());
        String type = intent.getType();
        TextView displayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp_textview);

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type!=null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity.java", "Intent verified");
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleSendText(intent, displayText);
            }
        }
    }

    void handleSendText(Intent intent, TextView displayText) {
        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        Log.d("MainActivity.java", sharedText);
        if (sharedText != null) {
            displayText.setText(sharedText);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried fiddling with the launchMode in the manifest but none of the options solved the issue.

Edit 1:

Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="chaitanya.im.example">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your manifest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normally, if another application launches your `Activity` (via ACTION_SEND, for example), your `Activity` will be launched into the existing task of the other app. So if you use 5 other apps and each of them launch your `Activity` using ACTION_SEND, you will have 5 instances of your `Activity`, each in a separate task.

If you want your `Activity` to run by itself, in its own task, and not in the other app's task, then you need to specify `launchMode="singleTask"` in the `<activity>` declaration in the manifest for this `Activity`. Then, when another app launches your `Activity`, the `Activity` will be launched in a separate task. If there is already an instance of the `Activity` running in that task, then Android will not create a new instance of the `Activity`, it will just call `onNewIntent()` and deliver the `Intent` that the other app used in the call to `startActivity()`.

Comment: `launchMode="singleInstance"` and implementing `onNewIntent()` solved the issue. But I don't understand why. Could you throw some light on that?

Comment: Well, the only difference between `singleTask` and `singleInstance` has to do with what happens if your `Activity` starts any other activities. In the `singleTask` case, if your `Activity` launches another `Activity`, the default behaviour is that it is started in the same task on top of your original `Activity`. In the `singleTask` case, if your `Activity` launches any other `Activity`, it will be launched in another task so that your task only ever contains a single `Activity`. That;s the only difference. If your `Activity` never launches another `Activity`, then there is no difference.

Comment: but for me the action.send variables such as text are not being passed when using android:launchMode="singleTask"